# Get output of shell command using RootTools

Tags: android, roottools

I would like to get the output of a shell command, "ls -l" for example using [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki/Usage) and pass it to a variable or array so that i can manipulate it.

This is the code that i  use but does not work.

```
final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
final Command command = new Command(0, "ls -l") {      
    public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                    s.append(line);
                    super.commandOutput(id, line);
                    System.out.println(s.toString());
        }                   
    };

    try {
         RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
    } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem? Exception thrown or command output empty?

Comment: No output is being shown by system.out.

Comment: I think nothing is being pass to the variable that i declared.